# How to copy files in shell that do not end with a certain file extension

Tags: unix, shell, copy

For example copy all files that do not end with .txt

Comment: To the close-voters: this is about shell PROGRAMMING and is therefore on topic for the PROGRAMMING web site called StackOverflow!

Answer (score 5):

Bash will accept a not pattern.

```
cp !(*.txt)
```

Comment: Really? This looks like history expansion to me.

Comment: Works like a charm here for me.

mkdir test

cp !(*.txt) test/

Comment: Ah. You must have `shopt -s extglob`. Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ls with grep -v option:

```
for i in `ls | grep -v ".txt"`
do
    cp $i $dest_dir
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many assumptions you can afford to make about the characters in the file names, it might be as simple as:

```
cp $(ls | grep -v '\.txt$') /some/other/place
```

If that won't work for you, then maybe `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 cp ...` can be used instead (though that has issues - because the destination goes at the end of the argument list).

On MacOS X, `xargs` has an option `-J` that supports what is needed:

> `-J replstr`
>
> If this option is specified, xargs will use the data read from standard input to replace the first occurrence of replstr instead of append-
>                ing that data after all other arguments.  This option will not affect how many arguments will be read from input (-n), or the size of the
>                command(s) xargs will generate (-s).  The option just moves where those arguments will be placed in the command(s) that are executed.  The
>                replstr must show up as a distinct argument to xargs.  It will not be recognized if, for instance, it is in the middle of a quoted string.
>                Furthermore, only the first occurrence of the replstr will be replaced.  For example, the following command will copy the list of files and
>                directories which start with an uppercase letter in the current directory to destdir:
>
> ```
> /bin/ls -1d [A-Z]* | xargs -J % cp -rp % destdir
> ```

It appears the GNU `xargs` does not have `-J` but does have the related but slightly restrictive `-I` option (which is also present in MacOS X):

> `-I replace-str`
>
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
>             names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
>             terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
>             character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

Comment: What if I have another file extension how would I prevent both from copying? Using this one: cp $(ls | grep -v '\.txt$') /some/other/place

Comment: @user: `grep -Ev '\.(txt|dat|htm|html)$'`

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on:

```
find . -not -name "*.txt"
```

By using:

```
find -x . -not -name "*.txt" -d 1 -exec cp '{}' toto/ \;`
```

Which copies all file that are not .txt of the current directory to a subdirectory toto/. the -d 1 is used to prevent recursion here.

Answer (score 1):

Either do:

```
for f in $(ls | grep -v "\.txt$")
do
  cp -- "$f" ⟨destination-directory⟩
done
```

or if you have a huge amount of files:

```
find -prune \! -name "*.txt" -exec cp -- "{}" ⟨destination-directory⟩ .. \;
```

Two things here to comment on. One is the use of the double hyphen in the invocation of *cp,* and the quoting of `$f`. The first guards against "wacky" filenames that begin with a hyphen and might be interpreted as options. The second guards agains filenames with spaces (or what's in `IFS`) in them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, where *destination* is the destination directory:

```
ls | grep -v "\.txt$" | xargs cp -t destination
```

**Edit:** added "-t" thanks to the comments

Comment: The problem there is that copy `cp` want the destination as the last argument, not as the first...

Comment: @Jonathan: GNU `cp` has `--target-directory=foo` for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
cp *^.txt /some/folder
```

(if you just want *files*)...

```
cp *.^txt(.) /some/folder
```

More information on `zsh` globbing [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC81) and [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87).